# Notice: Undefined Index with PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

This is my code in which i am getting errors :
Notice: Undefined index: sbjbs_username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jobs\session.php on line 3

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['sbjbs_username'];
$_SESSION['sbjbs_userid']; 
$_SESSION['sbjbs_memtype'];
$_SESSION['sbjbs_emp_username'];
$_SESSION['sbjbs_emp_userid'];
//$_SESSION['sbjbs_emp_username'];
//$_SESSION['sbjbs_emp_userid'];
$_SESSION['softbiz_jbs_provided'];
//$_SESSION['ID'];
//$_SESSION['ID'];
?>
```

Comment: what to do next of your code? where the code come from?

Comment: Are you trying to set them?

Comment: try with var_dump($_SESSION) and see whay you've set

Comment: The above code doesn't make make sense.

Comment: @PeeHaa Perhaps the user believes that it's the equivalent of `var sbjbs_username`?